# When to use a virtual attribute or pass data in a hash in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, virtual-attribute, memorycache

In my application, I have a `Widget` model, a `Feature` model with a **has_many through** association by `WidgetFeature` table.

As per the requirements, when I am sending a WidgetFeature object, I should append the feature_name to it as well, for the given feature associated.
There are two ways of going at it:

1. While sending the object, do this:

> ```
> widget_feature_object[:feature_name] = feature_name_value
> ```

and then I can access it in my controller or view, by `widget_feature_object[:feature_name]` because an object has (key, value) pairs, so I can add another too.

2 . Make `feature_name` a **Virtual Attribute** in `WidgetFeature` model, and then create *getter and setter methods* for it.

From what I know, that you should use virtual attributes when you want to create a different view different from the fields actually present in the model (e.g Full name = First name + Last name).
Does the same thing fits in here too?

**Also**, does Rails do some caching on objects, that might get in useful when you use virtual attributes and not when I use the first approach?

What are the pros and cons of each approach and which one suits the best as per my requirements?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would propose an alternative approach: use `delegate` ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate)).

In the `WidgetFeature` I would write:

```
class WidgetFeature

  belongs_to :feature

  delegate :name, :to => :feature, :prefix => true
end
```

then you will be able to write

```
f = WidgetFeature.first

f.feature_name #will return f.feature.name
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use attr_accessor when you want to be able to set a method. Otherwise just use general functions.

If you want to cache, look into [memoization](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/7/16/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-memoization)

Comment: I know what attr_accessor does, and memoization is of no use here, if you look closely at the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you insist on using the [] notation to access your attributes, but one path to follow is this one:

```
def [](attr)
  if attr == :feature
    feature    # Return the associated feature object
  else
    super      # Call ActiveRecord::Base#[]
  end
end
```

Of course you could nice it up with some metaprogramming to automatically detect valid associations.

I personally don't really like monkeypatching in this fashion, but since [] is a simple method you're probably safe. The upside is that this allows you to widget_feature[:feature][:name] and even widget_feature[:feature][:name]=

You get all the ActiveRecord functionality that you would with calling widget_feature.feature.

Comment: @Martjin: I understand what you are saying. But the question is about a choice between choosing virtual attributes or simply passing the necessary data in a hash. It's only about the data sending, which is the main concern, if caching does something extra with virtual attributes.
Could you answer the problems in a better way now